# How to specify a static distance between five views using Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create 5 view's in my xml layout,but i want to do with the same height and same distance that can adapt for all mobile screens. So far o got this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#283343"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="80sp"

tools:context="com.example.nathi.myapplication.MainActivity">


<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#fe98fe" />
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#048de8" />
```

The thing is, if i let the `layout_marginTop="80sp"` when i run on bigger screen there's a height difference !

Comment: You can achieve that with layout_weight parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LinearLayout with `weightsum`& `laout_weight`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#d3d3d3" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#d3d3d3" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#d3d3d3" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#d3d3d3" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"/></LinearLayout>
```

It will Look like this
[image]

Comment: Hi Dave! Look, it is almost there, but i want to keep the `android:layout_height="0dp"` to 5dp because i need to be "tiny" and be separated the same way and same distance that you did,that is the layout from windows phone project [here](http://prntscr.com/apiiyj) there's five "Lines" with a same distance, how to do that?

Comment: @NathielPaulino Buddy here distance between 2 view is generated by Margin 10dp so there is total of 20dp margin. You can Remove that margin line from all views .
add simple new View after your choice of background with 5dp height and width will remain match parent.

Answer (score 0):

let use layout_weight = 1;

example

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding = "50dp"
    android:background="#fe98fe" />
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding = "50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#fe98fe" />
<View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding = "50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#fe98fe" />
```

Let see the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use  Percent Support Library ,  and set same height percents for all your views:
from here 
[PercentFrameLayout docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html)

```
 <View
         app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
         app:layout_marginPercent="20%"
         />
```